# NavigationLink with conditional in a List

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I want to show the categories and subcategories of some data. I have the data obtained from json, when a category does not have subcategories they have `parent = 0` and if it is different from zero it is understood that said category has subcategories.

Then from the list of caregivers I wish to have a `NavigationLink` according to the value of`parent`.

**How can I have the `NavigationLink` with a conditional?**

If the category does not have subcategories you must go to the `Product ()` view otherwise you must go to the `Scategory` view

Something like that, to be added to the `Navigation Link`

```
if parent == 0 {
Product()
} else {
Scategory()
}
```

Basic Sample Code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private let cats = [
        "Category 1", "Category 2"
    ]

    //Here I am assuming this value, when changing to zero you must change the destination of `navigationLInk`
    var parent = 20

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(cats, id: \.self) { item in
                //Here, how can I add a conditional to the `NavigationLink` using the value of` parent`
                NavigationLink(destination: Scategory(item: item)) {
                    Text(item)
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Category")
        }
    }
}

struct Scategory: View {
    let item: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Subcategory View \(item)")
                .font(.largeTitle)
        }
    }
}


struct Product: View {
    let item: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Produc View \(item)")
                .font(.largeTitle)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Views]

Answer (score 1):

Use NavigationLink and Button in one List.

```
struct HomeView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(0..<10, id: \.self) { index in
                if index % 2 == 0 {
                    NavigationLink {
                        
                    } label: {
                        card(index: index)
                    }
                } else {
                    Button {
                        
                    } label: {
                        card(index: index)
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .navigationTitle(Text("Navigation & Button"))
        }
    }
    
    func card(index: Int) -> some View {
        Text("Category: \(index)")
    }
}
```

[Click here to check result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21lzF.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I should work with this:

```
            if self.parent == 0 {

            NavigationLink(destination: Product(item: item)) {
                Text(item)
            }
            } else {

                NavigationLink(destination: Scategory(item: item)) {
                    Text(item)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting your custom views into `AnyView` like this:

```
if parent == 0 {
    AnyView(Product())
} else {
    AnyView(Scategory())
}
```